# special symbols in value field of textInput

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use things like greek letters and subscripts in the value field of a textInput widget. I know how to do this for the label but the same thing doesn't work in the field. Here is  toy example

```
    runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("txt")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$txt <- renderUI({
       textInput("a", 
            label = HTML(" &pi;<sub>0</sub> works here"), 
            value = HTML("but not &pi;<sub>0</sub> here"))

    })    
  }  
))
```

This displays the the greek letter and the subscript properly in the label but not in the text field

Answer (score 0):

values cannot be html, you will need to use some other way to enter special character, "π\u2092" works,

alternatively to avoid knowing π:

```
value = paste0(intToUtf8(0x03C0), "\u2092")
```

note that it does not look so good because the subscript is cut:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("a", 
              label = HTML(" &pi;<sub>0</sub> works here"), 
              value = paste0(intToUtf8(0x03C0), "\u2092, works here!")),
    verbatimTextOutput ("txt")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$txt <- renderText({
      input$a

    })  

  }  
))
```